# Why no USB tethering app for Windows Phone 10?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, usb, developer-preview, internet-sharing

I recently USB paired my WP10 with my Win10 laptop and browsed the Windows Device Portal. From the network diagnostics displayed and the fact that my phone is reachable on loopback, it seems to me that it should be possible to write an application to enable the laptop to use the phone's wireless adapter. It surprises me that someone hasn't done this already, so it could be that it's been attempted. While I'm looking through the UWP and .NET APIs for classes capable of it, can anyone tell me sooner rather than later why it wouldn't be possible?

Btw, I already have unlimited tethering with my phone plan, but I'm trying to maximize throughput to my laptop, which I make much more use of than my phone.

Answer (score 1):

Only Microsoft can tell you why this feature is still missing. Unfortunately there hasn't been any public statement yet regarding this afaik. The only thing you can do is go to the feedback app and request / vote for it there.

Comment: It appears to me that the interest and will to implement a USB adapter for phone is simply lacking; Microsoft and most Windows Developers believe it would be supporting backward technology. There's an attitude of certainty that WLAN will continue developing greater transmission speed that wired connections will never catch up to. There's also the complacency that WLAN is 'secure enough', even while news reports indicate that cybercrime is becoming more and more widespread.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone is an operating system that has a number of challenges to come up with such apps that you have describes. If someone has not come up with one then be the one or rather support someone to do it so that we can all make windows phone better.
Meanwhile windows phone 10 is yet to get new upgrades to unleash a number of features that users need or have requested to have